# Insert into dependent tables using triggers in Oracle database 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, insert, foreign-keys

For example, I'm using 3 tables: **A, B & C**

I'm creating a trigger on table **A**. So inside the trigger, I insert a record into table **B** (as master of **C**), and after that I need to insert another  record into table **C**.

I'm using a trigger on the `A` table, because I need use values from the **A** table to create the record in table **B**, and then I use information to insert a new record into table **C**.

I'm using that code snipped  "RETURNING **new_B_Id** INTO **b_lastid**; " after inserting the first record into table **B**, to get the newly inserted `id`, but when I'm trying to insert into table **C**, this message is thrown:

> Doesnt exist a master record on table **B** .

Any idea about to solve it?

Comment: post the table structure and let me know what are all the exceptions you have handled in your trigger

Comment: "Doesnt exist a master record on table" is not an Oracle error. This is not a literature class, don't "invent" your own error messages - copy/paste what Oracle reported (ORA-xxxxx error code would help).

Comment: What you have outlined is the sort of approach which should work, so the problem will be in the details. Unfortunately only you can see your code so there's very little we can do to help. If you can't spot your bloomer you'll need to post a reproducible test case - it doesn't have to be the full table structures, just the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Often it happens that the exercise of simplifying the code to post leads to a lightbulb moment in which we spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, here is the simplest thing which might work and indeed it does work: there is [a sqlfiddle demo to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3d554/1).

```
create table a (a_id number  primary key
                , txt varchar2(24))
/
create table b (b_id number  primary key
                 , a_id number not null
                 , constraint b_a_fk foreign key (a_id) references a)
/
create table c (c_id number primary key
                , b_id number not null
                , constraint c_b_fk foreign key (b_id) references b)
/
create sequence a_seq start with 10
/
create sequence b_seq start with 20
/
create sequence c_seq start with 30
/

create or replace trigger a_trg
after insert on a for each row
declare
    new_b_id number;
begin
    insert into b (b_id, a_id) values (b_seq.nextval, :new.a_id)
    returning b_id into new_b_id;     
    insert into c (c_id, b_id) values (c_seq.nextval, new_b_id);
end;
/
```

So, the problem you're experiencing will lie in the gap between what I've posted above and what you have in your own code. As the issue seems to be `ORA-02291: integrity constraint` on the insert into `C` I would look closely at the foreign key constraint you've defined on that table: does it really reference the primary key on `B`?